# What is the pupose of TokenID increment in OpenZepplin implementation?

Tags: solidity, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I am exploring OpenZepplin implementation of `ERC721`. One thing I found in example of `Counters.sol` to increment/decrement tokenId. I do get that we do not tokenId for the uniqueness in case the owner holds multiple unique NFTs but why there is a need of increment of it? I assume that each NFT' Token ID is bind to the contract address. Why not just use `1` as a default token Id because that NFT will always be a unique?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What makes a token unique within an ERC-721 NFT contract is that token’s `tokenId`. The ERC-721 NFT standard doesn’t tell you *how* to assign `tokenId`s to tokens, but only requires that different tokens have different `tokenId`s. If a particular NFT contract allows NFTs to be minted one by one, a simple strategy that will guarantee `tokenId` uniqueness is to assign `tokenId = 0` to the first minted token, `tokenId = 1` to the second minted token, `tokenId = 2` to the next minted token, `tokenId = 3` to the next, etc., which is what OpenZeppelin’s [ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/token/ERC721/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol) is doing.

NFT contracts are usually deployed once *per collection*, so in this case a token’s `tokenId` needs to identify a token within the entire collection, as described above. However it *is* possible to use `1` as a “default `tokenId`” as you have suggested, but only if the NFT contract is deployed once *per NFT*. This isn’t common practice, because in the long run it could end up consuming a lot of gas, but it’s perfectly doable, and there might be scenarios in which such a strategy is preferable (e.g. if you are going to deploy a single special one-of-a-kind NFT, or if you actually required individual NFTs to have their own Ethereum address). Probably if you opted for this strategy of deploying a “singleton NFT contract” per NFT , you’d want to deploy the NFT implementation once, and then deploy a small *proxy* for every new NFT that would delegate calls to the common implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. What is usually done by the guys like OpenSeas: Are they creating new NFT per uploaded art or a single NFT have all required functionalities and then use `.mnit()`  method to upload all arts and define uniqueness?